# Setting directory permissions on Linux server

Tags: linux, permissions, putty

I am learning how to use Putty to access Linux servers and I am looking into setting directory permissions at the moment. For this, I did some simple test commands. I created a test directory and set the permissions to 0 like so

```
chmod 000 myTestDir
```

My understanding is that the first digit sets the permission for the owner of the directory, the second digit sets the permission for groups (which I am not sure what they are) and the third digit sets permissions for the rest of the world.

So now I tried to delete the folder in my ftp client, logged into the server using the same credentials as in Putty. I wasn't able to delete it which was the expected behavior since I set the permission to 0.

However, I was still able to delete the directory in Putty doing

```
rmdir myTestDir
```

Why am I able to delete the directory? I set the permission to non-readable, non-writable. Does using Putty command line automatically override those permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Use command `chattr +i -R folder_name` to do your directory unremovable.
`chmod 000` will denie creating/reading files and folders inside, not changing itself.

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour for a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent file or directory removal, you have to change permissions on the parent directory.

```
mkdir 0
cd 0
mkdir 1
chmod a-w .  # This removes write permissons on 0.
rmdir 1
```

Output:

```
rmdir: failed to remove `1': Permission denied
```

How did you try to remove the directory in ftp?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In ftp I tried removing it by simply deleting it.

Comment: @user1457366: With `delete` or `rmdir`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When I say ftp I am talking about a gui client. I am using FileZilla. So deleting in the ftp client for me just means hitting "Delete" on the file/directory.